# How do I interpret this T Test result - t.test() in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, t-test, interpretation

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  sample1 and sample2
t = 2.658, df = 95.421, p-value = 0.009217
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01615943 0.11150922
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y
0.5585566 0.4947222
```

I have this result for a T test using `t.test()` function in R - please correct me if I am wrong - I understand that the test shows significant difference in population for `sample1` and `sample2` at 95% confidence level. I also understand that the point estimate for the difference in the means of `sample1` and `sample2` is the `t-value = 2.658`

What I don't understand is the confidence interval:

Does it say that the difference in means of `sample1` and `sample2` at 95% confidence level should be between `0.016` and `0.111` if they come from the same population?

Or does it say that the range estimate can be `0.016` to `0.111` units more than the point estimate at 95% confidence level.

It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Perhaps this Q&A will help http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178166/interpreting-confidence-intervals-in-t-test?rq=1

Comment: Mean difference and t-value are different things. The mean difference is not 2.658, but rather (.5585566 - .4847222). That 95%CI is then the CI for your mean difference.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, What is t-value telling me then?

Comment: That is a long story... Basically it is a probability distribution that consists of many sample mean differences based on your sample size. It is centered at 0. You can see this as an all-encompassing results if the null hypothesis (two means are equal) is true. Now if your sample t-value is far enough, we can have reasonable doubt that perhaps the means are indeed different. And that threshold is set at 2.5% at each end, corresponding to the p-value threshold (5% chance). It turned out, for most t-distributions, the threshold is about 2 and -2.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, Thanks. What is the point estimate of the difference in  means of samples 1 and 2? How is t-value different from this estimate? Is t-value just the difference in means of the two samples in standard error units?

Comment: (0.5585566 - 0.4947222) = 0.0638344. As for what t-value actually is, it's one of the fundamental concepts so many resources are available out there. [here](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/statistics-and-quality-data-analysis/what-is-a-t-test-and-why-is-it-like-telling-a-kid-to-clean-up-that-mess-in-the-kitchen) is a short blog post, and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3azuAaOJack) is the start of an 8-part tutorial on independent sample t-test.