# Could you recommend a textbook for t-test and p-value?

Tags: t-test, p-value, references

I am a graduate student and now I have a trouble to understand p-value. I watched youtube videos, but they didn't really help. I want to know it a bit in depth. Could you please recommend a book for me?

Comment: A useful read https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/595373/56940

Comment: Freedman, D., Pisani, R., & Purves, R. (1998). Statistics (3rd ed). New York: W. W. Norton & Company.

Comment: Freedman, Pisani and Purves got to a 4th edition in 2007. Whether there will be another I have no idea (David Freedman died in 2008) but it barely matters. The book was written free of any notion of matching recent fads or fashions, statistical or otherwise. Even the 1978 first edition (if you can find a used copy in good condition) will be excellent for your purposes.